# Android SearchView onQueryTextChange doesn't work with ObservableOnSubscribe

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, searchview

I've got such code for searching streams by their name.

```
    compositeDisposable.add(Observable.create(ObservableOnSubscribe<String> { subscriber ->
        binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                subscriber.onNext(newText!!)
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                subscriber.onNext(query!!)
                return false
            }
        })
    })
        .debounce(250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .distinct()
        .subscribe { text ->
            val pagerPos = binding.streamsPager.currentItem
            val currentFragment =
                activity?.supportFragmentManager?.findFragmentByTag("f${pagerAdapter.getItemId(pagerPos)}")
            (currentFragment as StreamFragment).onSearchHolder.onSearch(text)
        }
    )
```

It works fine with onQueryTextSubmit, but ignores setOnQueryTextListener. So when I want to erase symbols and "reset" search I get nothing

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you want a `distinct()`? `distinct()` means that the observable will never emit the same item twice. Maybe you need `distinctUntilChanged()`

Answer (score 1):

use a wrapper class for your ObservableOnSubscribe and sealed class for your search events. Like this:

```
class SearchViewWrapper(private val searchView: SearchView) : ObservableOnSubscribe<SearchViewEvent> {

    override fun subscribe(emitter: ObservableEmitter<SearchViewEvent>) {
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                emitter.onNext(SearchViewEvent.onQueryTextSumbit(query))
                return true
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                emitter.onNext(SearchViewEvent.onQueryChanged(newText))
                return true
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Sealed class for events:

```
sealed class SearchViewEvent {
    data class onQueryChanged(val text: String?): SearchViewEvent()
    data class onQueryTextSumbit(val query: String?): SearchViewEvent()
}
```

Try to use it where you need(just example):

```
fun useIt(searchView: SearchView) {
    Observable.create(SearchViewWrapper(searchView))
        .subscribe(::handleSearchViewEvent)
        .addTo(yourCompositeDisposable)
}

private fun handleSearchViewEvent(event: SearchViewEvent) {
    when (event) {
        is SearchViewEvent.onQueryChanged -> TODO()
        is SearchViewEvent.onQueryTextSumbit -> TODO()
    }
}
```